# The SIAM Latex Template stopped working after Miktex update

Tags: pdftex, packages, miktex, templates, cleveref

I recently updated MikTeX packages, what I had not done in a while.

Then, when I compiled a paper I am working on, that I plan to submit to a SIAM journal, and therefore I am using its LaTeX template, it failed. The template is available here: https://epubs.siam.org/journal-authors#macros

I noticed the file would not compile. It seems to be a problem with the cleverref package, specifically with the cref command. An example of a error is

```
! Argument of \@fourthoffive has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.71 \cref{sec:main}
                    , our new algorithm is in \cref{sec:alg}, experimental
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
```

Then, I tried compiling the template article available in the link above, and it also failed, with the same error. I have tried looking for answers, and have been unlucky so far. I have no idea if the problem is a package conflict, the MikTex version, or the SIAM template file. The log-file I get when I attempt to compile ex-article.tex (provided in the link above) is available here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eb2qxlkB6aCiMkNwrB8Jsr7NGyTr1uoi/view

Comment: Please make your questions self-sustained. Add a small test document to your question and try to add the log file as a code block.

Comment: That being said, try to delete all the auxiliary files and recompile from scratch. If this does not help, try to update your latex packages. Several of your packages are a bit behind the current version.

Comment: I get no error but your hyperref and xr-hyper are older than mine you have `Package: xr-hyper 2023-05-16 v7.00y eXternal References (DPC)` texlive has `Package: xr-hyper 2023-06-25 v7.01a eXternal References (DPC)`

Comment: I have run miktex-console, no update is showing up for me. I have also tried deleting all auxiliary files and compile, it did not work

Comment: you can use this work around: https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/284#issuecomment-1588022830. When miktex updates hyperref it should no longer be necessary but the class should nevertheless stop to redefine \label and other core latex commands.

Comment: That worked! Thank you, I have spent too much time on this already

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to write an answer or should this be closed?

Answer (score 1):

As I understood it, the problem seems to be a problem with the hyperref package, that was patched very recently.

And because the update is so recent, it is not showing up yet on MikTeX-Console.

But, alas, the suggestion of Ulrike Fischer to use the trick in https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/284#issuecomment-1588022830 worked!

Comment: no, the problem is not with hyperref. The problem is that LaTeX has changed the \label command but the class overwrite this change.  A new hyperref contains a work-around but the class should correct its code.